# Deserialize a JSON array that contains an array?

Tags: c#, json, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities, json.net

When I try to deserialize the following with the .NET JavaScriptDeserializer, I get the error message: `Type 'People' is not supported for deserialization of an array`

When I use `JSON.NET` like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<People>>(args["xldata"]);`, I get a more detailed error message:

`Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'People' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.`

I am using Linq-To-Entities, so I don't think I can add any attributes to it.

`args["xldata"]` is a `Dictionary` with "xldata" as the key and the `JSON` string below as the value.

`[
    [
        {
            "CarrierHeaderId": 17,
            "DetailHeaderId": 54,
            "tds_client": "0000000996",
            "carr_no": "0000019",
            "name": "John Doe                                       ",
            "entry_type": "F",
            "carrier_type": "2",
            "scac_code": "1A  ",
            "cert_no": "2d        ",
            "address": "123 orange boulevard                              ",
            "city": "Orlando                                           ",
            "state": "St",
            "zip": "33333     ",
            "phone": "9993023938",
            "epa_num": "123       ",
            "fein": "AA        ",
            "host_carr_no": "BB     ",
            "host_route_cd": "1a3  ",
            "country": "US",
            "CarrierHeaderLastUpdate": "6/11/2013 11:07 AM",
            "term_id": "TDSTES8",
            "trailer_req": "0",
            "truck_req": "0",
            "access_from": "1159",
            "access_to": "2359",
            "access_days": "YNNYYYN",
            "ins_exp_date": "12/20/13",
            "locked": "",
            "lockout_date": "",
            "lockout_reason": "",
            "st_license": "",
            "st_permit": "",
            "icc_permit": "",
            "liab_amt": "",
            "haz_mat_excl": "",
            "veh_liab_exp": "",
            "veh_liab_amt": "",
            "excess_liab_exp": "",
            "excess_liab_amt": "",
            "work_comp_exp": "",
            "work_comp_amt": "",
            "host_locked": "",
            "host_lockout_date": "",
            "host_lockout_reason": "",
            "po_relno_req": null,
            "general_exp": "",
            "general_amt": "",
            "access_profile": "",
            "max_load_amt": "",
            "own_consumption": "",
            "full_redirect": "",
            "det_required": "",
            "seal_processing": "",
            "email_group": "",
            "email_address": "",
            "shipment_origin": "",
            "auto_confirm": "",
            "bulk_transaction_picklist": "",
            "ExciseNo": "",
            "ERP_Carrier": "",
            "CarrierDetailLastUpdate": "6/11/2013 5:03 PM"
        }
    ]
]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<People>>>` should work.